# Frequency for a particular column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can you help me solve this? I want to get the output mentioned from the example dataset

Here is an example DATASET ,

```
df
     col1  col2
  0   A     X          
  1   B     X  
  2   C     X   
  3   A     X
  4   B     X         
  5   M     Y  
  6   C     Y   
  7   C     Y
  8   A     Y
```

For a particular value in column 1 (let's say A) it should give a frequency of the values in column 2. A is there for X and Y so it should give 2. B is only in X so it should give 1 etc.

In this case the result should look something like

```
Name Frequency
 A      2
 B      1 
 C      2
 M      1
```

Comment: df['col_name'].value_counts()

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. If you want to hire a programmer, you'd rather go elsewhere.

Comment: @jrjames83 i don't think that would work , it would give A as 3 an B as 2 i don't want a duplicate value

Comment: @MehulGupta jrjames83's solution would work